# pdf reader that keeps pan/zoom while changing pages?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

When viewing PDFs with Acrobat Reader I zoom/pan page to exclude top & bottom margins from view. When I change page it always starts at the top (it keeps zoom but pans to top of the page).

Is there any PDF reader that keeps pan persistent across page changes?

I'm looking for something like SumatraPDF's "fit content", but with manual setting.

Answer (score 1):

you may solve this issue by using third party plug-in for Acrobat. and I suggest using **evermap AutoBookmark** where you can customize a zooming window and to top left coordination of the zooming window preserving the position of that window over the pages.

you can find more information about using Evermap AutoBookmark in the following link.

http://www.evermap.com/autobookmarktutorial.asp

Comment: I think this plugin functionality is limited to bookmarks/links only. IMHO it will not work with previous/next page - and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: no, when you set up your zooming window (dimension and position) it will produce bookmarks to all the pdf page preserving your setting.